# Can I use Protractor for TDD in MEAN stack

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, protractor

I'm very new to Unit testing and TDD. I'm clear with TDD concepts theoretically, but I'm having lots of impediments in implementing that. Most of the examples explains how to do unit testing for Multiply, adding two numbers, etc., which is not we really need in real time.

For angular, it is much better, we can check the values of array, existence of Controller, using the service, mocking the backend, etc., So now I have couple of questions,

1. How can do Unit testing for Backend process like how the request is being handled ?
2. My application mostly interacts with UI components, Can I use protractor in my TDD process, for example Drawing tool, how can I do testing without drawing(interacting) anything on it ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many **orm** framework available in nodejs to generate testdata if you want to generate data in your traditional DB and use your backend as it is.

**jugglingdb** and **sequelizejs** are the most popular one.

Even to make it more manageable you can implement **cucumber** or **jasmine** framework with protractor, so you can manage after and before hookups for individual test-scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Hardik, but I didn't ask for test report generating tool. My question is can I use Protractor in TDD workflow and Can I use Protractor for Canvas drawing testing ?